# Multiselect display items and selected items (p-multiselect)

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am having issues displaying the currently selected items (always returns blank) - most likely I am not iterating over the object properly. Although, unsure on the best approach to this. All I want is for all the options to be displayed in the multi-select and also the currently selected items (e.g. from database).

Component:

```
orders: any[] = [];

this.orderDetailService.getAllOrders().subscribe((orders) => {
  this.orders = orders;
});


private fetchOrderDetailData() {
  if (this.orderDetailId !== undefined) {
    this.orderDetailService.getOrderDetailById(this.orderDetailId).subscribe((orderDetail) => {
      console.log(orderDetail.DetailCategories);
      this.orderDetail = orderDetail;
    });
  } else {
    // Handle the case where this.order.OrderDetail?.Id is undefined
    console.error('OrderDetail Id is undefined');
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p-multiSelect [options]="categories" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories" defaultLabel="Select a Category" optionLabel="Name"
        display="chip"></p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

Currently:

- Able to display all options
- **DOES NOT** show the currently selected items (Which I want)
- Eventually I will need to add/remove these

The console.log(orderDetail.DetailCategories); is the one that displays the currently selected items and is an array of objects. Array [ {…}, {…} ].
Also the Category.Name is what I put as the option.Label but for the above array it is called CategoryName (so can't reference Name for that one)

**Edit 1**

Replicated behaviour:

https://primeng-multiselect-demo-cjrvx6.stackblitz.io

Note that:

- I already have one City which doesn't display by default on the multiselect. If I then chose an option you can see the selected value except it is empty.
- Also note that I have a different naming convention between cities and selected cities

What I want is to show all the selectedCities by default alongside all the other options (as a chip in the multiselect). Of course with the CityName. I will have functionality to add/remove these

Reason for different names is my project has a many to many relationship with

- Categories Entity for listing those options
- OrderCategories Junction table to combine the two
- Order Entity containing a collection of all entries from the junction table

Comment: The StackBlitz link you shared isn't same as your provided code in the question. But from the StackBlitz demo, your selected item's properties don't match with your `cities`: `[{ CityName: 'New York', CityCode: 'NY' }]` Change the property name should fix the issue: `this.selectedCities = [{ name: 'New York', code: 'NY' }];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different data types in selected items and the list of available options, you can use `optionValue` to make a property of the list as the ID, and in the [(ngModel)], you can pass an array of those IDs.

```html
<!-- template -->
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" 
    defaultLabel="Select a City" 
    optionLabel="CityName"
    optionValue="CityCode" 
    display="chip">
```

```js
// component
cities = [
    { CityName: 'New York', CityCode: 'NY' },
    { CityName: 'Rome', CityCode: 'RM' },
    { CityName: 'London', CityCode: 'LDN' },
    { CityName: 'Istanbul', CityCode: 'IST' },
    { CityName: 'Paris', CityCode: 'PRS' },
];
selectedCities = ['NY', 'RM'];
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-nnashy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I honestly tried to understand the essence of the question by rereading the text many times... But, unfortunately, the meaning escapes me XD.

I'll try to suggest an idea based on the use of MultiSelect.

The following attributes are required for the basic operation of MultiSelect:

- Input() options: any[]
- Value - ngModel or formControl
- if you use Object(s) as options:

  - optionLabel - key of label key in Object
  - optionValue - key of value key in Object

In practice I use all Object as value(don't use optionValue).

---

I will return to your example.

options <= categories - Where do you fill in this variable?
value <= selectedCategories - Where do you output this variable?

Mby here must be orders as options?

Comment: See my edited post and check out the stackblitz. First play around with the dropdown and you will see that the selectedCities only appears when you select an item from the dropdown (but shows an empty value)